# Does leaving the grass trimmings raise the lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass, fertilizer, cuttings

If I cut my lawn with a bio cutter, and therefore leave the grass trimmings on the lawn.

Will the dirt level raise over time?

My concern is if the dirt level will go above the side walk tiles, as my new lawn doesn't do today.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt grass clipping raise soil level. I am lazy and have a few flagstone pathways where grass ( weeds) are never cut. Those stones sink into the soil and must be lifted after about 10 years. My soil is quite sandy, if that makes a difference.